# How to have angular directive for two elements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a small menu on my page that is a directive. But as the user scrolls, I want that navigation to become sticky once it gets out of the viewport.

I have jquery code that involves cloning the element, and I've used this code in the past and tried to convert over to Angular in multiple ways. I tried just leaving it as one element and changing the ng-class but this does not have the same visual effect and looks bad so I determined that I do NEED two elements (the original and the sticky).

I tried cloning it in the directive link function, but the ng-repeat inside it does not run, so the menu is not populated with the links.

So I tried putting two < elements > in the DOM and it only renders the last one. What is the best way to have 2 elements go through the same directive? I'm so lost.

Directive link:

```
link: function( scope, element ){
        var scrollTimer;
        var origHeight = element.offset().top;

        element.clone().insertAfter(element).toggleClass('secondary original');

        angular.forEach(scope.days, function(value, key) {
            var date_data = {action: 'get_date', day: value.name};
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: ajaxUrl,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                data: date_data
            })
            .then(function(response){
                scope.days[key].date = response.data.date;
            });
        });
    }
```

Directive template:

```
<div id="day_header" class="original">
    <div ng-repeat="day in days" ng-class="{'active': active_day == day.name}" class="day" ng-click="changeActiveDay(day.name)" data-date="{{day.date}}">{{day.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: have to use angular $compile when you inject elements that contain directives

Comment: @charlietfl I changed link to compile and that worked slightly better, except my ng-repeat is just displaying {{day.name}} it's not actually compiling anything. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against using a clone. Have all elements set to `position: relative;`. and when the scroll moves passed the point, change them to `position: absolute;`.

Comment: I already mentioned I tried that, but it does not flow well with my layout. When scrolling back up, when you're close to the original positioning, you can see where it is missing from when it's transitioning from the sticky position.

Comment: I think this is still the answer. You need to play with the numbers to get it to *flow* properly.